# Why does an empty numpy array have a shape and what does it mean?

Tags: python, numpy

If I initialize a `numpy` array like so:

```
data = np.empty((413, 0), dtype=float)
```

It has a shape, but it's "empty".

What does it mean to be empty in this case? Is it filled with `np.nan` and if yes, why does it now show `np.nan`? If not, what is inside it? Does it only allocate memory?

Also, how do I check if it's empty? Clearly `.shape` does not work. But it is empty...

Can someone please clarify this concept?

Comment: One of the things you're wondering is what the array's elements look like. How *many* elements do you think this array has?

Comment: Note that `np.empty` is a completely different sense of "empty" than what you get by setting one of the dimension lengths to 0 (which you've also done).

Comment: I don't know how many elements it has tbh. I guess 0.

Comment: I removed the `duplicate` since it was a `pytorch` answer, not `numpy` (related but not identical).  Also this one has the complication that the size is 0.

Comment: You can't identify whether an array was created by `np.empty`, and shouldn't need to.  Just read the code.  In addition, with a size 0 (one dimension is 0), there aren't any elements to check, so it doesn't matter how it was created.  `zeros` and `ones` would create an identical array.

Comment: `np.ones` and `np.full` both create an array with `np.empty` and then immediately fill it with `copyto`.  `np.zeros` is compiled code, so its relation to `np.empty` is more obscure (and usually doesn't matter).

Comment: I might add that every `ndarray` has a `shape`.  It's an integral attribute, as is `dtype` and `strides`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.empty` doesn't really create an empty array. It creates an array with an *uninitialized data buffer* - the elements of the array are whatever arbitrary garbage happened to be in that memory. This is not random - it is often all zeros, or the contents of a recently deallocated array, or (potentially sensitive) data from some other recently deallocated object. An element could even be a signalling NaN, which could crash your program if you try to do any operations with it.

There is no way to test for this.

---

You've also specified a dimension with length zero. That makes your array really empty, in the sense that it has no elements. You can test for that with `arr.size == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

> Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.
>
> `empty`, unlike `zeros`, does not set the array values to zero, and may therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used with caution.

It might be an alternative to `zeros` if you plan to write all values anyways.

Comment: Thanks, so is it np.nan and how can I check if it's an empty array?

Comment: @Newskooler: You cannot assume the elements are nan. They are usually not.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy docs say the array will be initialized with arbitrary values. Yes, memory will be allocated for the entries.

https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

Comment: I see from the documentation that it's because I set the column to 0, I don't see anything. Had I set the column value to something different from 0, I would have seen random values...